# Azure Cache (Preview) item size limit

Tags: caching, azure

Is there a limit to a single item (object) size in Azure Cache Preview? 
I know that Azure Shared Cache has that limitation (8MB serialized) but I can not find that kind of information for the new Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no changes in the object size. Its the same - 8MB serialized.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is proof: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/a1378c00-9c9e-4db4-aadd-9c4240126996

Answer (score 0):

By default the caching imlementation uses 'standard' .Net Binary serialization. This is quite efficient, but I  had great results using Protobuf serialization:
http://nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/2.0.0.580
Encoding / decoding performance is stellar and it greatly reduces serialized object size:
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance
So give it a try in case you hit the 8MB limit.